# Any pyinstaller detailed example about hidden import for psutil?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, psutil

I want to compile my python code to binary by using `pyinstaller`, but the `hidden import` block me. For example, the following code import `psutil` and print the CPU count:

```
# example.py
import psutil
print psutil.cpu_count()
```

And I compile the code:

```
$ pyinstaller -F example.py --hidden-import=psutil
```

When I run the output under `dist`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _psutil_linux
```

Then I tried:

```
$ pyinstaller -F example.py --hidden-import=_psutil_linux
```

Still the same error. I have read the pyinstall manual, but I still don't know how to use the `hidden import`. Is there a detailed example for this? Or at least a example to compile and run my `example.py`?

ENVs:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Python: 2.7.6
- pyinstaller: 2.1

Comment: why down vote  this?

Comment: Probably for not giving the versions of python and pyinstaller you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Hi hope you're still looking for an answer. Here is how I solved it:

add a file called `hook-psutil.py`

```python
from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import (collect_data_files, collect_submodules)

datas = [('./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_linux.so', 'psutil'),
         ('./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_posix.so', 'psutil')]
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('psutil')
```

And then call `pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=(the dir contain the above script) script.py`

Comment: EDIT: the above solution is tested under Ubuntu 14.04. To make it work on windows, you probably need to include something like `_psutile_windows`.

Comment: For pyinstaller 3 you must use the following code to import **collect_submodules** : 
`from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules`
[PyInstaller Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstall` is hard to configure, the `cx_freeze` maybe better, both support windows (you can download the `exe` directly) and linux. Provide the `example.py`, In windows, suppose you have install python in the default path (`C:\\Python27`):

```
$ python c:\\Python27\\Scripts\\cxfreeze example.py -s --target-dir some_path
```

the `cxfreeze` is a python script, you should run it with `python`, then the build files are under `some_path` (with a lot of `xxx.pyd` and `xxx.dll`).

In Linux, just run:

```
$ cxfreeze example.py -s --target-dir some_path
```

and also output a lot of files(`xxx.so`) under `some_path`.

The defect of `cx_freeze` is it would not wrap all libraries to target dir, this means you have to test your build under different environments. If any library missing, just copy them to target dir. A exception case is, for example, if your build your python under Centos 6, but when running under Centos 7, the missing of libc.so.6 will throw, you should compile your python both under Centos 7 and Centos 6.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is as follows:

1. Install python-psutil: `sudo apt-get install python-psutil`. If you
   have a previous installation of the `psutil` module from other
   method, for example through source or `easy_install`, remove it first.
2. Run `pyinstaller` as you do, without the `hidden-import` option.

Answer (score -1):

still facing the error
Implementation:
1.python program with modules like platform , os , shutil and psutil
when i run the script directly using python its working fine.

2.if i build a binary using pyinstaller. The binary is build successfully. But if i run the binary iam getting the No module named psutil found.I had tried several methods like adding the hidden import and other things. None is working. I trying it almost 2 to 3 days.
**Error:**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
**Command used for the creating binary**
pyinstaller --hidden-import=['_psutil_linux'] --onefile --clean serverHW.py

i tried --additional-hooks-dir= also not working. When i run the binary im getting module not found error.

Comment: You should improve at least the formatting of your answer. I could also do it, but I can't understand what you want to say with your answer. Is a question? Are you suggesting a solution?